# USB data transfer

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I am still learning about mcus and how to interact with them, and so far USB communication looks like a black box for me.

Basicall a question is, how do i communicate with usb device from window/linux/mac machine ?

What needs to be done in order to set up the device configure it and allow user space application to send/receive data. should i just use generic windows driver and use libusb to talk to a device ? should i make a driver my self to avoid complicated installation for end user like installing libusb dll or patching it.

Comment: If your device is fully custom, take a look at winusb: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/automatic-installation-of-winusb. You'll provide just an inf for your users, but no need to write kernel code. If your device conforms to a standard such as HID or CDC, then Windows provides a driver.

Comment: @LosFrijoles well basically a device should stream data to a host, and accept 3 commands. that basically it. i mean host should poll data on interval or send a command to it and display data in application. so i need a way to interface with evice via userland application

Comment: Anton, maybe you should start with researching "USB Device Class", Something about Microsoft driver development kit, read other MS articles on supporting USB classes.